# Git push failed when I updated the cocoaPods

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1, iosdeployment

In order to fit iOS 10,I have to update these 3-part in cocoaPods,so I had updated the cocoaPods to it's newest version.APP works fine,but when I use `git push`, the terminal require me to input username and password for github,however,the terminal showed:

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/'`.

I am sure the username and password I put into is right.

Before I asked this question here I had ask for help on Google and find a solution:`Pull first,then push`.

But the embarrassing thing is that I had commit my code.That is to say,if I use `git pull` I will lose all my work today,that's terrible,so I wonder if there any better way to solve it.

When I hit `git remote -v` in terminal there showed something interesting:

`origin https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git (push)`

I am surprised about how cocoaPods changed my project's remote url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I use `git remote set-url origin xxx` solve this problem.